# Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: Updating PackageType is not supported"

Tags: aws-lambda, containers, aws-cdk, aws-pipeline

I received the following error from Cloud Formation for AWS Lambda.

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: Updating PackageType is not supported"
```

There was a Lambda stack successfully deployed; however, using CDK & pipelines, I attempted a git commit/push where instead of a 'vanilla' Lambda deployment, I pursued a containerized Lambda deployment (where the vanilla had previously successfully provisoned resources.)

Am I to interpret this error as that the Stack must be manually deleted/destroyed before these changes can be shipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue when my stack previously had a JS function and replaced it with a custom container image running a Python app.

The reason why it happens is described in detail here: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/discussions/10805

In short, it's a limitation of AWS - once you deployed a function with one PackageType, you can't just replace it with something with a different PackageType.

What helped in my case: I just commented out the section with this specific function entry in my serverless.yml and redeployed - this removes just the function I need to update. Then I uncommented the definition, deploying again, this time using a custom container.

Comment: This makes sense to me- out of curiosity, would commented out DynamoDb or S3 behave similarly? If a function is deleted, re-deploy and no long lasting harm. Not so w/ a Db...

Comment: This worked for me after a long struggle